# Django 1.11 queries not working

Tags: python, django-1.11

I'm trying to set up something using Django 1.11 and python for my job where it will display a list of projects submitted by the logged in user. The user can click on the Project name and it will take the user to that project to edit it if they need to. I have it showing the list of projects but when the user clicks the name I get an error. It works fine when there is only 1 project displaying for that users. The error and my code is below.

**MultipleObjectsReturned at /edit/
get() returned more than one Project -- it returned 2!
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit/
Django Version:     1.11
Exception Type:     MultipleObjectsReturned
Exception Value:

get() returned more than one Project -- it returned 2!**

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index/',views.Index.as_view(),name='index'),
    url(r'^form/', views.Form.as_view(), name = 'form'),
    url(r'^edit/', views.EditProject.as_view(), name = 'editProject'),

]
```

views.py

```
class Index(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    template_name = 'sitename/index.html'
    form_class = IndexForm

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Project.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

class EditProject(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
template_name = 'irbSite/form.html'
form_class = ProjectForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('irbSite:index')

# works only when there is 1 project object
def get_object(self):
    return Project.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
```

index.html

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}

   {% if project_list %}
     <tr>
        <th>Project Number</th>
        <th>Project Name</th>
        <th>Is Complete</th>
        <th>Is Approved</th>
    </tr>

{% for project in project_list  %}
    <tr>
     <td><a href="{% url 'irbSite:editProject'%}">{{project.project_id}}</td>
    <td>{{project.project_name}}</a></td>
    <td>{{project.is_complete}}</td>
    <td>{{project.is_approved}}</td>
{% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% else %}
 <p>You dont have any current IRB forms. Select "Submit New Project" on the left to start one.<p>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.filter` to get multiple object while querying.

**Ex:**

```
def get_object(self):
    return Project.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Hey Rakesh, I am able to get multiple objects but after that I need to be able to click on one to review it. Thats when I get the error about MultipleObjectsReturned